# Steering rack bushing needs to be replaced. Do I need to replace the whole rack?

Tags: steering, lexus, bushing

My wife's car recently started slipping whenever she turns to the right. By slipping, I mean that she will be taking a hard right, then her steering will slip to the left and she has to crank the wheel hard to the right to make up for it. It only happens occasionally, but is very unsafe and needs to be repaired.

She took it into Les Schwab today and was told that the steering rack bushings were bad and needed to be replaced. They also said that they could not just change the bushings, but needed to replace the entire rack. I have been misled by Les Schwab before, so I thought I would ask if this is indeed the case. Can the bushings be replaced independently of the rack?

The vehicle is a 2000 Lexus RX300.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can buy and replace the worn bushings, either from the Dealer, local parts store or performance parts sellers.

https://www.startpage.com/do/search?query=2000+Lexus+RX300.+rack+bushings&cat=web&pl=chrome&language=english

Comment: Thank you Moab! I had a feeling. Do the bushings typically outlast the rack? I would hate to replace the bushings just to find out that I need to replace the whole rack a few months down the road.